# Follower foursquare user

Tags: python, api, foursquare

How to find out using the api of foursquare who is a follower user use Python wrapper? List of users ids.

```
import foursquare

user = client.users()
# after parse user json count followers zero. But this error.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the library I see:

```
def friends(self, USER_ID=u'self', params={}, multi=False):
    """https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/friends"""
    return self.GET('{USER_ID}/friends'.format(USER_ID=USER_ID), params, multi=multi)
```

Have you tried `friends = client.users.friends()`